# umask in /etc/profile and /etc/login.defs

Tags: umask

I don't understand how `umask` works in these two files: my machine doesn't use pam_umask module.

If I change user and create a new file/directory, the `umask` used is taken from `/etc/profile` (the `umask` in `/etc/login.defs` is unused).

Which is the purpose of `umask` in `/etc/login.defs`?

From the manpage seems it is used only for the permission definition of an home directory for new users: is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question. The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/login.defs.5.html) for `login.defs` explains:

> UMASK (number)
>
> The file mode creation mask is initialized to this value. If not specified, the mask will be initialized to 022.
>
> useradd and newusers use this mask to set the mode of the home directory they create
>
> It is also used by pam_umask as the default umask value.

`/etc/profile` is executed by the login shell. When not logging in via shell, umask set in `/etc/profile` is not effective.

[`pam_umask`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/pam_umask.8.html) module can be configured to set the session umask to the value defined in `login.defs`. Compared to setting umask in `/etc/profile`, umask set by `pam_umask` is also effective in situations when logging in does not execute login shell (graphical session, ssh session without shell).

Comment: So in my system umask in /etc/login.defs is used only for permissions of a newly created home: can you explain me the situations where the umask in /etc/profile is not effective? You have written about different deafault shell: is this the case? If I have two users with different shells (e.g. sh and bash), how umask is managed? is it always taken from /etc/profile?

Comment: Most shells execute `/etc/profile` when invoked as login shell. A typical example when `/etc/profile` is not executed and umask set there is not effective when logging in graphical session or when logging in via ssh and providing a command to execute.